Seperate Sword Sprite to Player
I am aware a common approach in game development for attack animations is to seperate the player from the weapon and 'stitch' them together in runtime depending on what weapon is equipped.
This would prevent having to animate the entire player again for every possible weapon - you would just need to animate a new weapon!
An example of this I have seen is with the Zelda: A Link to the Past sprite sheet. Links body is seperated from the sword and the sword is overlayed on top of or behind link when attacking (or so I assume).
See https://www.spriters-resource.com/snes/legendofzeldaalinktothepast/sheet/58952/.
The part im unsure of is how to actually go about implementing this in code.
How would I figure out where to place the sword relative to the player? And whether I need to rotate the sword or flip it? Or even what sword frame to get?
For context, I'm using LibGDX to make my game.
I'm thinking you would probably store the sword frames you want to use in some array, maybe being held by the player, so you could swap out the frames for different ones. For each attack frame you could then define what sword frame to use from this array, an offset from the player, a rotation, and a horizontal/vertical flip value.
But then how would you define these offsets and rotations? Would you hard code them or is there some way of defining them in data alongside the body animation frames?

Different engines use different approaches. Are you coding one on your own? And this is not unique to weapons, all gear / cloth / body parts are done the same way as well. If you take a look at that spritesheet, there is no full link.

@Zibelas I'm using LibGDX, so not a lot is given to me in terms of this.

This should be included in your question.

I would use a sprite sheet of animations with each frame using a fixed size and offset, a base fixed location relative to the character sprite, so the memory used and associated lookup delays are minimized.
To save System Memory to GPU transfer time, multiple weapon animations can be stacked on top of each other assuming the frame size(x,y) is set to the largest weapon on the sheet and the offset is the same for all.
Creative use/or non-use of transparency in the overlay can allow the hands and arms to follow the animation, on top of the base sprite.
